# SOAP WebServices Read Timed Out

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I am migrating some webservices from WebSphere/Axis to CXF, I have done all the necessary configuration to the get the working up to a point. But I keep getting this error when I run my web application:

```
    20-Jan-2020 14:27:47.333 WARNING [RLC-0120085637269] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doDefaultLogging Interceptor for {http://logicalprovisioning.atm.com/gtc/processorder}ProcessGtcOrderService#{http://logicalprovisioning.atm.com/gtc/processorder}ProcessOrder has thrown exception, unwinding now
        org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not receive Message.
                at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:65)
                at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
                at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)
                at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:441)
                at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:356)
                at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:314)
                at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:140)
                at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy115.processOrder(Unknown Source)
                at com.logicalprovisioning.common.gtc.shared.RequestListClient.run(RequestListClient.java:423)
        Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SocketTimeoutException invoking http://localhost:8080/GTC/services/ProcessGtcOrderSoapHttpPort: Read timed out
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1400)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1384)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:671)
                at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:63)
                ... 9 more
        Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
                at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
                at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
                at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
                at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
                at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
                at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
                at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
                at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735)
                at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
                at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1587)
                at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
                at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream$2.run(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:377)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream$2.run(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:373)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.getResponseCode(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:373)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.doProcessResponseCode(HTTPConduit.java:1597)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1625)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1570)
                at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1371)
                ... 12 more
```

I have set the timeouts like:

```
getBindingProvider().getRequestContext().put(BindingProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, connectTimeout);
getBindingProvider().getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endPointUrl);
```

The value of connectTimeout is 3720000. Which is like 1 hour. Can you please tell me, what am I doing wrong here? Or are there anymore configuration that I missed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only timeout you have configured (assuming `BindignProviderProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT` is equal to `"com.sun.xml.internal.ws.connect.timeout"`) is the timeout for completeing the initial connection.

Since you put that timeout to about an hour I assume you are expecting the service to be slow and that's the reason for the read timeout. Try configuring the request timeout using "com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout" to something longer than the default of one minute.

```
getBindingProvider().getRequestContext().put("com.sun.xml.internal.ws.request.timeout", requestTimeout);
```

or by setting the receive timeout on the HTTP Conduit in any of the ways described at http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport(includingSSLsupport)-UsingConfiguration